# Chrome developer tools: save javascript state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to save the current state of a page and it's JavaScript variables in Chrome devtools, in order to later reload that same state?

As some background: I'm working on a project that has a question and answer system. This mechanism is handled by JavaScript and my workflow is awful at the moment because I'm coding question number ten and need to answer the first nine questions each time I need to test my code.

I would like to answer questions 1-9, save the state of the variables on the page, make changes to question 10 code and test after first reloading the state until question 9.

Comment: it sounds like you need to write some reusable code instead of implementing each individual question separately.

Comment: @DanielA.White certainly, and questions 1-9 are reusable. It's question 10 that needs to have an exception coded into it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to make this work exactly as you describe, since the concept of `the variables on the page` isn't easy to work with. What would happen if you add a remove a variable name in the code?

There are a few things you could try.

**1. Remove the first 9 questions from the quiz**

Are they necessary for testing?

**2. Find out what variables are set and then back them up**

For example, if the `window.questionIndex` and `window.answersGiven` properties describe the state of the page you could back them up like this:

```
function backup(){
    localStorage.setItem("questionIndex", JSON.stringify(window.questionIndex));
    localStorage.setItem("answersGiven", JSON.stringify(window.answersGiven))
}
function restore(){
    window.questionIndex = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("questionIndex"));
    window.answersGiven = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("answersGiven");
}
```

**3. Automate the process of clicking through the quiz**

Would a script like this do the trick?

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
     $("#answer1").click()
}, 100)
setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 100 * 9)
```

**4. Develop the last question independently before integrating it**

Create an empty page and load only the module for question #10 on it. Once the coe works as expected integrate it into the full quiz.